# Google remote api для Python 302 ошибка

Tags: python, google-api, oauth2

Хочу переключить аутентификацию гугл-апи с ClientLogin на Oauth2. Было написано

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(
        'project_id',
        '/remote_api',
        auth_func,
        'project.appspot.com',
    )
```

Сделал сервисный ключ, добавил env variable как json файл с ключом. Все по инструкции
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi и  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
Переписал код на

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
        'project.appspot.com',
        '/remote_api'
    )
```

По идее должно работать. По факту 302 ошибка "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found Too many auth attempts." Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Спасибо.